# Has many through stop printing the entire object after loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, view, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am practicing has_many through but I am stuck when the looping through the contents. It displays the whole object and not just the item want.

Models:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :appointments
    has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :appointments
   has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

Controller:

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @patients = Patient.all
    @appointments = Appointment.all
    @physicians = Physician.all
    end

    def show
    @patients = Physician.find(params[:id])
    @appointments = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    @physicians = Physician.find(params[:id])   
    end
end
```

patients/show.html.erb:

```
<%= @physicians.patients.each do |physician| %> <br><br>
    <%= physician.name %>
<% end %>
```

After entering some random data to test I get the following result at http://localhost:3000/patients/1:

```
Jannie Runolfsdottir III 

Eudora Moen [#<Patient id: 4, name: "Jannie Runolfsdottir III", phone: "356-388-3102 x3079", created_at: "2015-05-14 23:09:36", updated_at: "2015-05-14 23:09:36">, #<Patient id: 5, name: "Eudora Moen", phone: "(372) 713-5045 x3012", created_at: "2015-05-14 23:09:36", updated_at: "2015-05-14 23:09:36">]
```

I based my code from [Views in a has_many :through relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630711/views-in-a-has-many-through-relationship) and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

The question is, **how do I stop the whole object from displaying?** I only want the names to display. It is behaving as I used the .inspect method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the beginning of the first line from `<%=` to `<%`.

The `=` tells it to print the object returned, which in the case of `each` is the whole object.